# Using the total client width with CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, width

I have a page with dashboard similar to iGoogle. I need to have the page work on the available client width. 
I wrote a JavaScript to get the width and distribute it evenly amongst the divs. This script sets the *element.style{width: 540px;}* for the divs and it works very well when the page loads. Its
something like:

`window.onload = function SetWidth(){ document.getElementById(dashCell.id).style.width = (Math.round(window.innerWidth / 2)) + 'px';};`

Now comes the pain point. The page has an *UpdatePanel* with an *Timer* which does a PostBack every 5000 milliseconds. This spoils the design as the page is loaded again and the *element.style* is lost.

I have read about fluid CSS and also considered using *min-width* and *max-width* CSS attributes. But the need of the hour is to get it working this way. I need a working solution for now, but better and right ways to achieve this are definitely welcome.

Comment: Why not use percentages for widths? http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/hPK5b/

Comment: @saluce: The controls which load inside the containing _divs_ have no size limitation. So, I use `overflow: visible;`  for these _divs_ with a fixed width or percentage width for container divs. But at least the outermost div should have a fixed width or else the page just keeps growing. I will still give this a try (its a lot of change) and get back to you asap. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @saluce: The percentage width method did not work as expected. Possibly because of some `tables` being used in some places on the page. Nevertheless, I take your suggestion as a valid answer and a point in doing it the right way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must re-run your script and re-fix your css style on every UpdatePanel as

```
    <script type="text/javascript">     
   function SetWidth(){ 
      document.getElementById(dashCell.id).style.width = (Math.round(window.innerWidth / 2)) + 'px';
    }
    // set the onload call
    window.onload = SetWidth;

    // capture the UpdatePanel javascript events
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      
    }

     // after the updatepanel complet refix the css
    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
         SetWidth();
    }
    </script>
```

Or save the initialize value somewhere and just apply them after the updatepanel refress.

Comment: This works just the way I needed it to. Thanks a lot! I have a question though. The user has options to choose between 7 different layouts for the dashboard. These are _UserControls_ and there is no _UpdatePanel_ here. But my width setting script (`SetWidth();`) resides here. Now, the _aspx_ page which contains these layouts has the _UpdatePanel_. Ideally, where should the script suggested by you go? _apsx_ or _ascx_

Comment: @Horizon as you describe it better to go global, on aspx.